What do "messy" weapons do, exactly?

messy: This weapon spreads a lot of blood and gore around.

So... what exactly does that mean? How should I reflect in game the messy label on Spellslinger's lighting spells?

It means it makes a mess.
That's just a true thing that happens. You blow up a Mongolian Death Worm with a lightning spell, now you've got Mongolian Death Worm blood and guts all over the place, in a way that wouldn't happen if you, say, crushed its foresegment with a big ol' mace that lacked the messy tag. Or froze it solid with an ice spell.
And on the surface all that means is there's one more thing that's true.
What more it might mean is usually left up to the Keeper.

Maybe it's good, in that now the Expert can fill up a whole bunch of sample vials and investigate the mystery some back at their haven.
Maybe it's bad, in that Mongolian Death Worm blood is a poisonous acid and you've created a combat hazard that the hunters will have to work around.
Maybe it's bad but on a longer scale, in that you're fighting in a place that's important to some bystanders, who are sure to have Strong Opinions about all the Mongolian Death Worm blood and guts everywhere.

Your players looked at you to find out what the messy tag would mean. So say what your prep demands, say what honesty demands, and make a move that follows.
